# Undefined is not a function appendTo issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery that looks like:

```
$(function() {
   var productTextTemplate = $('#product-text-template').html();
   var productTemplate = $('product-template').html();
   var product = productTextTemplate.appendTo(productTemplate);
   alert(product);
});
```

What I'm trying to do is combine:

```
<div id="product-template">
   Hello
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="product-text-template">
   World
</div>
```

so it becomes:

```
<div id="product-template">
   Hello
   <div id="product-text-template">
      World
   </div>
</div>
```

but I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I also made a JSFiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/q76EQ/.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Hint: what does `"foo".appendTo("bar")` do? (And why might I have chosen the value of `"foo"` in the example, instead of a jQuery object?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.html()` from `var productTextTemplate = $('#product-text-template').html();`

```
$(function() {
    var productTextTemplate = $('#product-text-template');
    var productTemplate = $('product-template').html();
    var product = productTextTemplate.appendTo(productTemplate);
    alert(product);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ِAlso, you may forget to write `#` to `product-template` to be

> var productTemplate = $('#product-template').html();